# Spin groups and the Quaternionic Representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, vector-bundles, spin-geometry

[Quaternionic representation is also known as the pseudo real representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternionic_representation).

For the $Spin(n)$ group, it looks that [only $Spin(3+8k), Spin(4+8k), Spin(5+8k)$ representation are pseudo real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternionic_representation#Examples).

[image]

Questions:

> 1. Let us accept that the group isomorphism shows that 
>      $$Spin(4)=SU(2)\times SU(2)=Spin(3)\times Spin(3).$$ 
>      Let us accept that we know $Spin(3)$ representation is pseudo real.
>
> Then Don't we have the $Spin(3)\times Spin(3)$ is in the real representation (pseudo real $\otimes$ pseudo real can make a real representation (!?)), thus the $Spin(4)$ is also in the real representation?
>
> But according to the above, the $Spin(4)$ is also in the pseudo real representation?
>
> 2. We know that $Spin(n)/\mathbb{Z}_2=SO(n)$,
>      since [$Spin(3), Spin(4), Spin(5)$ representations are pseudo real representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternionic_representation#Examples), what can we say about the corresponding representations of $SO(3), SO(4), SO(5)$ --- can they also have a pseudo real representation?

Thanks for the answer in advance!

Comment: For the 1st question, see for example, the-tensor-product-of-two-pseudoreal-representations-real? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243164/why-is-the-tensor-product-of-two-pseudoreal-representations-real

Comment: I am having serious difficulty understanding what it is you're asking because of language issues. For instance, in the sentence *"don't we have the Spin(3)xSpin(3) is in the real representation"*, what representation of Spin(3)xSpin(3) are you referring to, what real representation are you referring to, and what do you mean by a being "in" a representation? (Like, a subrepresentation?) When you say the "Spin(n)" representation, are you referring to the representations of Spin(n) that the chart is talking about?

Comment: And in your second question, what are the "corresponding representations of SO(3), SO(4), SO(5)" you refer to? I don't think the representations of Spin(3), Spin(4), Spin(5) that the chart is talking about descend to representations of SO(3), SO(4), SO(5).